# Bad Escape String in variable returning image src in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager to implement the 'article' JSON markup and return a couple of variables for changing elements on specific pages. One of the elements I am trying to return is an image src.

Right now I am using a DOM element to return this that is using a CSS selector. The HTML element that it is targeting is:

```
 <div class="field-item even">
<img src="THISISTHEIMAGEURL.jpg">
</div>
```

and I am targeting in GTM by collecting: div.field-item.even > img with an attribute name of src
[This is a screenshot of how I'm targeting in GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gpls.png)

Right now when I test this in preview mode the URL of the image is appearing exactly how it is supposed to and everything looks great.

When I check this using the Google Structured data testing tool I am returning an error that says "Bad Escape String" and a URL for the image that has slashes going both ways like [http://\www.mysite.com/](http://%5Cwww.mysite.com/)\image1.jpg/\

I have been doing some research, and it seems I may need to use a custom javascript variable or something in order to make this work.

I was trying to use something like this:

```
 function() {
var src = document.querySelector(‘.fielditem.even > img').src;
}
```

but then I get an error in GTM telling me I need a return value. Unfortanately, my javascript skills are pretty poor and after some more research I tried something like this:

```
 var picture = document.getElementsByClassName(".fielditem.even");
var src = picture[0].firstElementChild.src;
```

but I still am getting the same error, that I need a return value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `-` sign in both of your selectors.

```
.fielditem.even > img
```

Instead of

```
.field-item.even > img
```

If you execute the script below it works fine, when *querying* the correct *classes*.

```js
var image = document.querySelector('.field-item.even > img');
var src = image.src;

console.log(src)
```

```html
<div class="field-item even">
  <img src="https://resources.risingstack.com/risingstack-logo-2017.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return a value from your function:

```
function imgSRC() {
  return document.querySelector('.field-item.even > img').src;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and pulled the correct image src using the javascript variable, but I'm still getting the 'bad escape string' error when I look at it in the structured data tool. Is there a way to pull the URL and make sure that the slashes aren't turning? This is what I am getting for the URL string that I'm pulling in: http:\/\/altoona.psu.edu\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/feature_article_primary\/public\/white1.jpg?itok\x3djc5Wri6V This may be something in the structured data testing tool, because in the console mode everything is appearing correctly, but I wasn't sure.